# bootstrap tab('show') not work on dynimcally loaded 'tab-content'

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, partial-views

I am using ASP.NET MVC and boostrap 3

I am using bootstrap tabs,
my main view like this

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="tabs-container">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="test">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-operations">Operations</a></li>
              <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-categories">Categories</a></li>
          </ul>
          @Html.Partial("_Ordering", Model)
      </div>
  </div>
```

the partial view `_Ordering` like this

```
<div class="tab-content" id="ordDiv">
    <div id="tab-operations" class="tab-pane active">
        // some content not important
    </div>
    <div id="tab-categories" class="tab-pane">
        // some content not important
    </div>
</div>
```

and I am using unobtrusive-ajax to update the partial view

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("cancel", "PartialOrdering", null,
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", Url = Url.Action("PartialOrdering"), UpdateTargetId = "ordDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, null)
```

the content of the tab updating correctly wihout any problem.

the problem is i want to show the tab which already was exists before the ajax request refreshed the content.
I used js code for this like this

```
var a = $('#test li.active').find('a');
a.click();      // not showing the content of the tab
a.tab('show');  // also this not showing the content of the tab
```

the previous code does not make any error in the console, but the desired tab is not shown

Comment: Have you included the reference to bootstrap.js file in your DOM?

Comment: @Aamir are you kidding, if I was not adding bootstrap.js the `tab` function will give an error in the console, which is not my case, As I said there is no any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a specific tab here you will need to pass the id of specific anchor tag and based on that anchor you can call the `tab()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  activeaTab('tab-categories');
});
function activeaTab(tab){
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewaeLkvv/

Comment: **first** this is just copy and paste from another answer on the SO, before I asked this question, I made a very wide search about this and I founded this answer before and it did not helped me. **second** I doing the same thing exactly, just I am getting the anchor element in different way, actually `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]')` is the same for `$('#test li.active').find('a')` which I already have. My problem is `tab` function itself not working. **third** you are hard coded the tab to show, but I want to show the shown tab before making the ajax request.